# Vue 2 nested Router (not nested routes)

Tags: nested, vuejs2, vue-router

In documentation of Vue Router : https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html we have capability to create some nested route. But, that require which all subroutes are known by the main router.

What I want is each Vue component can be capable to manage it's own inner routing component from itself and use the base parameter to plug it from parent router.

There is no way to use more one router? And let each component manage that own router system? As Express.js allows it : http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

---

I tried this to allow for example a true URL system with `history` mode and for one of component, another Router in `hash` mode to use tab:

```
var test = new Vue({
    ...
    template: `
        <router-view></router-view>
    `,
    router: new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [{
            path: '/',
            component: {
                ...
                template: `
                    <p>Accueil</p>
                `
                ...
            }
        }, {
            path: '/test/',
            component: {
                ...
                template: `<div>
                    <p>Test</p>
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </div>`
                router: new VueRouter({
                    mode: 'hash',
                    base: '/test/',
                    routes: [{
                        path: '/',
                        component: {
                            ...
                            'template': `
                                <div>Tab1</div>
                            `
                            ...
                        }
                    }, {
                        path: '/tab2/',
                        component: {
                            ...
                            'template': `
                                <p>Tab2</p>
                            `
                            ...
                        }
                    }]
                }
                ...
            }
        }]
    }
   ...
});
```

First level work as expected :

```
`/` display `<p>Accueil</p>`
```

but for inner I have

```
`/test/` that display `<div><p>Test</p><!----></div>`
`/test/item2/` that display `<div><p>Test</p><!----></div>`
```

and I expected this

```
`/test/` that display `<div><p>Test</p><p>Item1</p></div>`
`/test/item2/` that display `<div><p>Test</p><p>Item2</p></div>`
```

---

**What's wrong ? I think it's because `<router-view></router-view>` in nested component refer to first router, not the second one? There is no way to create a `<custom-router-view></custom-router-view>` to create a router inside a component (itself managed by a router) ?**

---

EDIT : I provided a JSFIDDLE to how I expect that works

- https://jsfiddle.net/6du90epg/553/

Comment: I could not clearly understnd the exact scenario whzt you want, but I have created a jsFiddle( https://jsfiddle.net/o01afgy2/2/ ) for my own purpose. Have a look if that could help you, because i think that could relate to you

Comment: whatever you are trying to do, nesting the router s the wrong way to go about it, what are you trying to build